# Hierarchical data from DB - to join or not to join

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, hierarchical-data

I am trying to find a clean and performant solution for this problem, but am stuck somehow.

Trivia:
-ASP.Net C# application (.Net 3.5)
-MS-SQL Server 2005

This is how the data looks like:
Category -> Template -> Instance

A Category can contain multiple Templates.
A Template can contain multiple Instances.

There is a class for each of these 3 and a corresponding database table with a lot of columns.

I want to load a complete category from the database into a C# Category class object, including all the related template and instance objects.

I have two options now:
1) *Do a join on all 3 tables and read all the data at once.*
**Upside**: A lot faster on the database side, all information in one query.
**Downside**: I transmit a lot of redundant data, because in each row there is the same category and template data for each instance.

Example (simplified):

```
CategoryID | CategoryName | TemplateID | TemplateName | InstanceID | InstanceName  
1 | FirstCategory | 1 | FirstTemplate | 1 | FirstInstance   
1 | FirstCategory | 1 | FirstTemplate | 2 | SecondInstance  
1 | FirstCategory | 1 | FirstTemplate | 3 | ThirdInstance  
1 | FirstCategory | 1 | SecondTemplate | 4 | FourthInstance
```

2) *I query each table on its own, first collecting the category data, then the related template data with the category ID and so on.*
**Upside**: Intuitive aproach, easier to handle on the code side, no redundant data is fetched.
**Downside**: Multiple queries to the server, probably slower.

What is the best way to go here? Am I missing an option?
Solution 1 seems to have better perfomance, but it looks "unclean" to me. I would have to get data for a category out of a whole bunch of data rows.

If I choose solution 1, which is the best way to fetch the category and template data?
Read it from the first data row and create a new instance once the value changes?
Do some sort of grouping?

Thanks in advance! This problem is giving me headaches since days.

Comment: I'm confused, if you use option #1 why is there redundant data? If you organize your classes in such a way that the outer class Category only contains the ID or Primary Key for the inner classes then its not redundant data. With most ORM's I've used thats exactly how its done.

Comment: Maybe the simplified example is missleading: In option #1 the complete category and template data (not only the ID and name) will be included in every row. So its quite redundant to have the information multiple times for every Instance where it doesnt change.

Comment: I need the information for categories and templates to fill the classes with data, but if I join as in option #1, I have it multiple times for each instance row. Example: CategoryID | CategoryName | CategoryLocation | CategoryXYZ | TemplateID | TemplateName | TemplateLocation | TemplateXYZ | InstanceID | InstanceName | ...

Comment: Are both of the relationships here 1:N, or is N:M a possibility?

Comment: In fact the relationship between Category and Template is N:M. I left that out for simplification and because it did not really affect the question when I am only fetching data for 1 specific Category. If one would want to get data of all categories, this would have to be considered, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Entity Framework on a project I'm doing at the moment.  While profiling it under certain scenarios, it indeed uses option 1 and brings back the table with redundant data.  So it seems that Microsoft opted for this approach, and they own the entire stack so presumably know how to make a good decision about this exact problem.

There may be some heuristic that decides to use option 2 under certain scenarios, but I haven't seen it in my profiling.  Furthermore I haven't seen EF ever return multiple result sets in a single query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! I think I will change my code to option #1 for optimal performance. I was unsure if the redundant data wasn't a sign for bad design, but that Entity Framework goes the same way gives some confidence. I will mark your answer as accepted, but I think most of the answers here are extremely helpful to get an understanding of the different possible ways to solve the problem and their advantages.

Comment: Glad to help.  Post back here and let us know if you find anything interesting once your system's up and running.  This is definitely something I'll be keeping an eye on in my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third option: do a 'select *' on each table and then do the join in memory. You could use LINQ for some lazy evaluation:

```
  class Category
  {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<Template> Templates
    {
      get
      {
        return Repository.Templates.Where(t => t.CategoryId == this.CategoryId).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit: you can use the same logic for the Template/Instance relationship:

```
  class Template
  {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public List<Instance> Instances
    {
      get
      {
        return Repository.Instances.Where(i => i.TemplateId == this.TemplateId).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I didn't think of that. Seems to be a better way than option #2, because I only have to execute 3 queries (1 for each table). But what would be the best way to make sure I only collect the Instance-Objects that belong to my Category? In the SQL Select with the CategoryID via joining the Template table or through collecting all the related Template IDs in code and then use IN() in the SQL query?

Comment: You don't need any additional SQL since everything is in memory. I made an edit to also show the logic for the Template/Instance relationship.

Comment: But if I only want to get the data for 1 specific Category (which I do), I dont need to perform a complete "SELECT *" on the Instance table (which contains a lot of data).

Comment: This will cause bucketloads of round trip calls to the DB unless you preload everything into your repository.

Comment: @atticae: I missed the point that you only want to read one Category and not all of them. So yes, you would have to collect all the related Template IDs in code and then build an SQL query with a large IN() clause. But maybe you could just add a CategoryId column to your Instance table. It would be redundant, but makes your query a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: you're using ADO / Stored procs and you have a normalised data structure.

You could return 3 resultsets from one stored procedure call.

```
1) select c.* from category c where c.id = @categoryId

2) select t.* from templates t
    join category c on t.categoryid = c.id 
    where c.id = @categoryId

3) select i.* from Instance i
    join templates t on i.templateid = t.id  
    join category c on t.categoryid = c.id
    where c.id = @categoryId
```

And sequentially populate your objects via a sqldatareader using sqldatareader.read() and sqldatareader.Nextresult()

It really does depend on the size of the data you are returning and how often you will be requesting this data as to whether you use set-based data retrival or something like above.

Comment: Yes, all the assumptions are true. I have never worked with multiple resultsets from 1 Stored Procedure, will have a look into that, thanks! The data will be requested very often. Its an ASP.Net application and each time a user opens a category page, the DB call is made.

Answer (score 1):

For a small amount of data Option 1 sounds good, however you should change the class structure and do composition for Template and Instance, meaning Template class should have a collection of Instance and Category will have collection Template and you can get rid of redundant data.

Option 2 is prefreble if the data is huge and your network bandwith is really good to make frequent DB calls.

Comment: I already have the class structure in the way you described, I just didnt describe the classes in detail in the question. For example Category.Templates is a List<Template> which is meant to hold all templates of this category. The data amount is not too big yet, but it might grow fast and I want the application to scale well. It's an ASP.Net application and the data of a category will need to be accessed every time a user loads a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

If the hierarchies aren't too deep and the number of children on each level is resonably small, I usually start with option #2. The intuitive approach as you described it. It lets us get away with using whatever methods we already have (getTemplates(), getInstances(234) etc).

But from a performance perspective, executing one query with a 3-table join and processing the records in sorted order will likely be the faster alternative (Option #1).