# Filling a hierarchical class structure with data

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical class structure like this:

Category -> Template -> Instance

A category contains multiple templates, a template contains multiple instances.

If I query the data from the database via a join over all 3 tables, the data looks something like this:

```
CategoryID | CategoryName | CategoryType | TemplateID | TemplateName | TemplateXYZ | InstanceID | InstanceName  
1 | "CatA" | "TypeX" | 1 | "TempA" | "X" | 1 | "InstA" 
1 | "CatA" | "TypeX" | 1 | "TempA" | "X" | 2 | "InstB"
1 | "CatA" | "TypeX" | 1 | "TempA" | "X" | 3 | "InstC"
1 | "CatA" | "TypeX" | 1 | "TempB" | "Y" | 4 | "InstD"
```

(just an example, the real data tables have a lot more columns)

What is the best/common way in C# to fill the classes with this kind of data when cycling through it with a data reader?

From the top of my head I would do it this way:

```
while(data.Read())
{
  // Create new objects each time the ID changes and read the data from the first row
  if(data["CategoryID"] != lastCategoryID) {
    lastCategoryID = data["CategoryID"];
    cat = new Category(data["CategoryName"], data["CategoryType"]);
    catList.Add(cat);
  }
  if(data["TemplateID"] != lastTemplateID) {
    lastTempateID = data["TemplateID"];
    template = new Template(data["TemplateName"], data["TemplateXYZ"]));
    cat.Templates.Add(template);
  }
  template.Instances.Add(new Instance(data["InstanceID"], data["InstanceName"]);
}
```

Is there a better, more elegant solution to fill the hierarchical class objects? Maybe using LINQ or Dictionaries?

Note: This question is related to my other question about the [best way to gather hierarchical data from a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563314/hirarchical-data-from-db-to-join-or-not-to-join). I split it up because this are two separate issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you do seems like a good way to work it.  Just make sure you sort the data in your query by and ID columns you have.  Sort by category then template.  This will ensure you don't go back to one of those IDs and create the object again.

Also - if a template can be in multiple categories, you will have to store each template in a list somewhere to make sure you don't duplicate them over categories.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, a template can indeed be in multiple categories. Even though I am still somehow unhappy with getting data that is equal for many rows from only the first one, I guess I will implement it this way, if there is no better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As you read from the data reader, populate an object with the data from each row. At this point don't worry about the duplicates:

```
var rawData = new List<Incoming>();
while (data.Read())
{
    rawData.Add( new Incoming(data[0], data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7]));
}
```

where

```
public class Incoming
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryType { get; set; }
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public int TemplateXYZ { get; set; }
    public int InstanceID { get; set; }
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }

    public Incoming(int categoryID , string categoryName , int categoryType , int templateId,string templateName ,int templateXYZ , int instanceID , string instanceName    )
    {
        CategoryID =categoryID;
        CategoryName = categoryName; CategoryType = categoryType; TemplateID = templateId;
        TemplateName = templateName; TemplateXYZ = templateXYZ; InstanceID = instanceID; InstanceName = instanceName; 
    }
}
```

then you can use LINQ to get the individual levels of the hierarchy out:

`var categories = rawData.GroupBy (d => d.CategoryID    );`

Answer (score -1):

Something like the following would provide you with a direct to class approach:

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("datafile.dat");

var query = from line in allLines
            let data = line.Split('|')
            select Category
                {
                    CategoryID = data[0],
                    CategoryName = data[1],
                    CategoryType = data[2], 
                    Template = new Template { TemplateID = data[3],
                                              TemplateXYZ = data[4],
                                              Instance = new Instance { InstanceID = data[5],
                    InstanceName = data[6] }
                                    }
                };
```

Comment: No offense, but did you even read the question? I query the data from a database and your answer doesnt even have anything to do with hierarchical data structure.

Comment: Yes I read it and that's why I gave you a solution that takes your structure and puts it into an object.  I put new as opposed to your Categories object.  I assumed you knew that you could then instantiate your template and instance objects inline as well which would give you the hierarchy you wanted.

Comment: Now I updated the posting so that you can see it within a hierarchy.  Usually when I write this kind of code I don't put it all in-line like this - I usually create them individually and then put together the child objects into their parent but that's just a preference.

Comment: Oh yeah... and don't use a datareader.  use linq.  it's the way to go when dealing with data.  you can massage the data however you like within your queryables and a datareader is just and old clunky mess.